# Where is the Ubuntu App store?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I don't have an Ubuntu phone but am considering getting one if I can find suitable apps. Is there a link/website that mirrors the on-device app store?

Comment: I found this one https://uappexplorer.com/apps but it seems incredible that there's no Canonical-provided one.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go, but note that It is unofficial.

https://uappexplorer.com/apps